# How to compute the MPS representation for a sequence of asymptotically gapped quantum spin chains

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-spin, spin-models, spin-chains, tensor-network

Suppose I have a sequence of gapped, spin-$1/2$, translationally invariant quantum spin chains $\{H_1, H_2,H_3\cdots\}$ with interactions of range $\leq 2$ (i.e. no further than nearest-neighbors).

Furthermore, these chains are such that $H_N$ is the Hamiltonian for a chain of length $N$. **However, we are not just trivially extending a fixed chain: the interactions in the Hamiltonians are also changing as $N\to\infty$**.

Now suppose that the gaps $\{\Delta_1,\Delta_2,\Delta_3,\cdots\}$ are converging to a finite value, i.e.
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\Delta_N~~\text{exists.}$$
Furthermore, the groundstate in the many-body Hilbert space is converging as well to a thermodynamic groundstate. My question is then: does a MPS representation for the thermodynamic groundstate exist? If so, how would I go about calculating it efficiently?

Comment: *Furthermore, the groundstate in the many-body Hilbert space is converging as well to a thermodynamic groundstate.*  ---  What does that even mean (given that these states live in different Hilbert spaces)?  Could you give a formal definition?

Comment: I'll think about it. I'll get back to you in a few hours